# Performant 2D rendering with Android's Canvas API

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, android-bitmap

Over the last month, I've taken a dive into trying my hand at a simple 2d side scroller using Android's default canvas APIs.

In short, my question boils down to "Is the Canvas API performant enough to pull 60fps with a simple side scroller with a multi-layer, parallaxing background?".

Now hear me out, because I've tried a ton of different approaches, and so far I've come up fairly empty handed on how to squeeze any more efficiency out of what I've attempted.

---

First, to address the easy problems:

1. I'm not allocating anything in the game loop
2. The Surface is Hardware Accelerated
3. Bitmaps are being loaded prior to starting the game, and drawn without scaling.
4. I don't believe I'm doing anything significant aside from the bitmap drawing in the game loop (mostly updating position variables and getting time)

---

The problems started, as you may have guessed, with the parallaxing BG. Seven layers in total, though I've been experimenting with as few as 3 while still unable to maintain 60fps. I'm clipping the parts that are overlapping to minimize overdraw, but I would guess I'm still drawing ~2-3x overdraw, all summed up.

As the game runs, I often start out at ~ 60fps, but about 30/40 seconds in, the fps drops to about 20. The time is random, and it seems to be a state of the phone, rather than a result of anything in the code (force killing the app & restarting causes the new app to start at ~20fps, but letting the phone sit for a while results in higher fps). My guess here is thermal throttling on the CPU...

Now I'm testing on a 5x, and naively thought these issues might disappear on a faster device (6P). Of course, due to the larger screen, the problems got worse, as it ran at ~15fps continuously.

A co-worker had suggested loading in small bitmaps and stretching them on draw, instead of scaling the bitmaps on load to the size they would appear on the screen. Implementing this by making each bitmap 1/3rd the size, and using the canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, destRect, Paint) method to compensate for size and scale yielded worse performance overall (though I'm sure it helped the memory footprint). I haven't tried the drawMesh method, but I imagined it wouldn't be more performant that the plain old drawBitmap.

In another attempt, I gave an array of ImageViews a shot, thinking the Android View class might be doing some magic I wasn't, but after an hour of fiddling with it, it didn't look any more promising.

Lastly, the GPU profiling on the device remains far beneath the green line, indicating 60fps, but the screen doesn't seem to reflect that. Not sure what's going on there.

Should I bite the bullet and switch over to OpenGL? I thought that Canvas would be up to the task of a side-scroller with a parallaxing background, but I'm either doin' it wrong™, or using the wrong tool for the job, it seems.

Any help or suggestions are sincerely appreciated, and apologies for the long-winded post.